# Strange effect with Nulltermination char inside of string

Tags: c++

Simple Code example: [Godbolt-Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nrWY9dr8E)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using u16 = uint16_t;

int main(){

  //char str[] = "0123456789\0abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz";
  char str[] = "0123456789\00123456789\00123456789";

  auto str_len = (sizeof(str)-1);
  cout << "stringlength: " << str_len << "\n";

  for(int ii=0; ii<str_len; ++ii){
    cout << u16(str[ii]) << ",";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

stringlength: 28
48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,**1**,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,**1**,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,

which is the same array content as when viewed with a debugger...
Here Termchar, 0 and 1 replaced with a single char with value '1'

but when I change for the other definition of char str[] (the commented out one...)

I get  48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,**57,0,97**,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,116,115,117,118,119,120,121,122,

which is correct.

So did I hit a strange unicode thing, or how to explain that effect?

PS: I use that char xyz[] definition, so (sizeof()-1) can be used as compile time strlen() calculation...

Comment: OK seems to be an octal escape sequence... but how to prevent it to be interpreted this way?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Guess the effect in that case would be 100% identical if used in pure C. So I tagged with both by intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to stop this from being interpreted as an octal escape sequence would be:

```
char str[] = "0123456789\0" "0123456789\0" "0123456789";
```

Or just use `\000` as the null character:

```
char str[] = "0123456789\0000123456789\0000123456789";
```

Comment: ok same solution as me. but syntax is quite ugly :-)

Comment: @schnedan I added an alternative syntax. Pick whichever one you like.

Comment: good idea... now I can guess what my peers know about... C String concatenation rules or octal sequences :-)

Comment: @schnedan if you do the concatenation one, it might be tempting for someone to merge the literals to "reformat". I'd use the octal literal one because at least people won't mess with it unless they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution - but with an ugly syntax is:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using u16 = uint16_t;

int main(){

  char str[] = "0123456789\0" "0123456789\0" "0123456789";

  auto str_len = (sizeof(str)-1);
  cout << "stringlength: " << str_len << "\n";

  for(int ii=0; ii<str_len; ++ii){
    cout << u16(str[ii]) << ",";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```